# VBA - Excel - Scraping website using IE - How to avoid forever loops when user close IE application while I'm waiting for readystate?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to access an internal webpage that requires authentication. Once the user login in correctly, I look for an specific pattern in the application webpage and turn IE.visible = False. I've managed to make it work, but if for ever reason the user close the IE window before the authentication is completed, my macro looses control and remains waiting an answer forever. 
Is there any way to prevent it from happening?
This is my code:

```
Sub myapplication()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim elements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection: Dim element As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim URL As String: Dim flag As Boolean

    logindate = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy"): clockon = Timer: delay = 10

    URL = "http://app1.htm"

    IE.Visible = True: IE.navigate URL

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    Set elements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("normalText")

    flag = False
    While flag = False
        For Each element In elements
            If InStr(element.innerHTML, logindate) Then
                IE.Visible = False: flag = True
                Exit For
            End If
            clockoff = Timer
            If delay > clockoff - clockon Then flag = True
        Next
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your code launching the IE and make it visible so that the user can finish the login process and then after executing some code you make the IE visible false.

You said that if the user closes the IE window manually during the authentication then your code loses the control.

There are several approaches you can try to handle this issue.

You can try to launch the IE browser in **fullscreen**. So it will not show any browser window controls and close button.

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.FullScreen = True
```

Note that With this approach, the user can use the ALT + TAB key to switch the window, and then the user can try to close it manually.

Another thing you can try is to use the [OnQuit event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768340%28v%3Dvs.85%29).

OnQuit event will get fired when the IE browser gets closed. So you can try to set the objects to Nothing on this event or take the necessary steps to reset your code. In this way, you can keep control of the code.

You can refer to the steps below to implement the OnQuit event.

1. Create a Class module with the name clsIE.

[image]

2. Add the code below in the class module.

   Option Explicit

   ```
   Public WithEvents IE As InternetExplorer

   Private Sub Class_Initialize()
       Set IE = New InternetExplorer
   End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       Set IE = Nothing
   End Sub

   Private Sub Ie_OnQuit()
       MsgBox "Closed now"
   End Sub
   ```
3. Create a new module and add the code below in it.

[image]

```
 Option Explicit

    Dim objApp As clsIE

    Sub Tester()
    '// Ivan F Moala
        Set objApp = New clsIE

        With objApp
            .IE.FullScreen = True
            .IE.Visible = True
            .IE.Navigate ("http://example.com")
        End With

    End Sub
```

Now if you run the module and try to close the IE browser manually then it will show a message. Further, you can try to modify the code as per your requirements.

Reference:

[Code in IE's Close event](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?15381-Code-in-IE-s-Close-event)

Comment: Hi Deepak,  simply **AMAIZING!!!**. It works perfectly. You made my day! Thanks a lot.